# WooCommerce 8.5+ triggers loading a ton of unnecessary scripts even when wc is disabled for non-wc-pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Until now, I used this function to prevent WooCommerce loading resources on non WooCommerce pages:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_woocommerce_styles_scripts', 999 );

function remove_woocommerce_styles_scripts() {
if ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ) {
    if ( ! is_woocommerce() && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() ) {
        remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'load_scripts']);
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', [WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'localize_printed_scripts'], 5);
        remove_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', [WC_Frontend_Scripts::class, 'localize_printed_scripts'], 5);
        }
    }
}
```

With all this, my non WooCommerce pages were freed from unnecessary WooCommerce styles and scripts. No additional scripts were loaded. The performance was good.

But with the latest release 8.5.2 something changed, a ton of scripts are suddenly loaded:

Handles:

- wp-polyfill-inert-js,
- regenerator-runtime-js,
- wp-polyfill-js,
- react-js,
- wp-hooks-js,
- wp-deprecated-js,
- wp-dom-js,
- react-dom-js,

*and many more...* A lot of stuff that wasn’t needed before.

I investigated and found a way to remove most of them:

```
//remove a ton of script from non-woocommerce pages
function deregister_polyfill(){
   wp_deregister_script( 'regenerator-runtime' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_polyfill');
```

This prevents WooCommerce from triggering / loading most unnecessary scripts.

There are only two still lingering:

- Handle: wc-cart-fragments-js-extra,
- Handle: wc-order-attribution-js-extra.

Are they needed on non WooCommerce pages? I do not understand this behavior at all.

Why is WooCommerce suddenly triggering all these scripts? 
Is this a dependency issue and if so, what script is responsible for this occurrence? 
Has anyone else noticed the loading of all these scripts?

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: It is the new «Order Attribution» feature that triggers the scripts mentioned above. Read: [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wc-8-5-2-loads-a-ton-of-unnecessary-scripts/#post-17397013) Problem resolved. Thanks for formatting the post properly